# Javascript Rollover Confusion

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi there I am trying to create a rollover for the following code but can't seem to figure out how to do it.

```
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<script type="javascript" src="../javascript/rollover_library.js"></script>
<script>
    var $ = function (id) { return document.getElementById(id); }
    var rollover;
    window.onload = function () {
        rollover1 = new Rollover("image1", "../images/flying_bats.jpg");
        rollover2 = new Rollover("image2", "../images/rat1.jpg");
        rollover3 = new Rollover("image3", "../images/strobe1.jpg");
    }
</script>
```

Above is javascript. What does the second part of the rollover script actually do? The part with the ("image1", "../images/flying_bats.jpg") in it? Or what *should* go there? I think that's where I am messing up.

```
<aside class="sidebarR">
    <h1>Customer's who bought this product also bought:</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <figure>
                <img id="image1" src="../thumbnails/flying_bats.jpg" alt="Flying bats" >
                <figcaption><a href="#" class="underConstruct">Flying bats</a></figcaption>
            </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
            <figure>
                <img id="image2" src="../thumbnails/rat1.jpg" alt="16-inch rat" >
                <figcaption><a href="#" class="underConstruct">16" Ugly rat</a></figcaption>    
            </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
            <figure>
                <img id="image3" src="../thumbnails/strobe1.jpg" alt="Mini strobe" >
                <figcaption><a href="#" class="underConstruct">Mini strobe light</a></figcaption>                   
            </figure>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </aside>
```

Comment: Which rollover-lib are you using? Do you see any JavaScript errors in your browsers console?

Comment: <script type="javascript" src="../javascript/rollover_library.js"></script>
should be the library no? If you're asking where its from, I couldn't tell you its part of the instructions my professor gave... D:

Comment: Looks like its creating 3 rollover objects on page load but without knowing what the "rollover_library.js" is there isn't much to go on.

Comment: So it must be an error of how I linked the JS to this HTML page?

Comment: Thats odd because the HTML starts in "cat.html" so I ../ back up to the "products" folder / into the "javascript" folder and / into rollover_library.js

Comment: You need to explain what you're trying to accomplish. "Creating a rollover" doesn't really give much to go on.

Comment: Does this help at all?: Complete the embedded script in the <head> section by adding simple JavaScript codes to apply the Rollover() function to the images with id “image1”, “image2” and “image3” in the cat.html. If not, let me know anything else you may need.

Comment: What does your code do or not do? Did you try debugging it? Place a breakpoint on one of the calls to `Rollover` and trace down inside it.